# Calling objects with numbers at the end in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is a sample code of what I'm trying to work on. I think it's probably a simple thing but the teachers on the front end course I'm in don't have an answer for me (either in the "here's the format to use" or "here's the proper way to do what you're trying here".)

```
var part1 = {
    type = 1,
}   

var part2 = {
    type = 2,
}

var part3 = {
    type = 3,
}

var partArray = [part1, part2, part3];
var carArray = [];
var truckArray = [];

for (i = 0; i < partArray.length; i++) {
    if (part[i].type === 1 || part[i].type === 2) {
        carArray.push(part[i]);
    }
    if (part[i].type === 3) {
        truckArray.push(part[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: the teacher doesn't have an answer? did the teacher tell you that the code is invalid? if not, I'd ask for a teacher that knows what they are teaching

Comment: you loop through partArray ... which you try (badly) to populate with objects ... then use the index (i) on something other than partArray ... clearly you need to start the course over from the beginning

Comment: The class is front end, primarily focusing on CSS and HTML with just a bit of supplemental JS, so I understand it being a bit out of scope?

Anyhow, the question is, it doesn't work. I think it's trying to read it literally and go looking for object part[i] rather than part1, part2, etc. as it goes down sequence.

Comment: I see the problem, but I have a kid getting a CS degree, so I'm feeling fatherly. It will probably serve you best in the long term if you figure this one out yourself. Some tips: (1) google is your friend. (2) look carefully at the error messages you get from javascript. (3) get a copy of jslint or jshint. These will look over your JS and tell you whether it's valid.

Comment: did your teacher teach you how to assign properties to an object ?

Comment: Also, you're not going to get far on SO with "It doesn't work." Here, you have to be specific about what is going wrong, what research you've done to address the problem, what you've tried to get around the problem, and what happened when you tried those things. You have to show that you've done some work on the problem yourself. "Show your work" like they say in school.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a few things incorrectly. First is how you create the properties in your part objects. Second is you are accessing a variable that doesn't exist `part`. I know you are trying to access `part1`, `part2`, `part3`. The thing is you already have those in your array, so the easiest is to access through there. Try this:

```
var part1 = {
  type: 1
}

var part2 = {
  type: 2
}

var part3 = {
  type: 3
}

var partArray = [part1, part2, part3];
var carArray = [];
var truckArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < partArray.length; i++){
  if (partArray[i].type === 1 || partArray[i].type === 2){
      carArray.push(partArray[i])
  }
  if (partArray[i].type === 3){
      truckArray.push(partArray[i])
  }
}

console.log(carArray)
console.log(truckArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using part instead of partArray

```
for (i=0; i < partArray.length; i++){
    if (partArray[i].type === 1 || partArray[i].type === 2){
        carArray.push(partArray[i])
    }
    if (partArray[i].type === 3){
        truckArray.push(partArray[i])
    }
}
```